# Multiple contact names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Customers with a column CustomerName and a column ContactName.
Image you have a customer named Patrick and the names of people you are allowed to contact are Bart en Thomas. How can you do that in mysql? In my assignment, it's mentioned a customer can have up to 4 ContactNames.

Should I create multiple columns like 2nd contact name, 3rd contactname,...
Or is there a possibility to put the different contact names of a customer in 1 column?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Normalized structure would use a related dependent table. You could use 4 contactname columns and then deal with the headaches of a non-normalized structure.

Comment: @June7 thank you for your answer. But what do you mean with a "related dependent table"?

Comment: A table with customers and then another table for customer contacts where each contact is a record. Second table is dependent on first (record must exist in first table for there to be associated records in second). Tables are related by primary/foreign key fields. This is conventional design for relational database.